# Mount a LUKS partition without manually supplying a passphrase

Tags: linux, luks, dm-crypt

I'd like to add a LUKS partition to a remote VPS. However, the VPS must automatically re-boot itself occasionally (about every 10 to 14 days) because it auto-installs security updates. Is this compatible with cryptsetup/LUKS?

If I'm reading this [Digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-encrypted-file-system-on-a-digitalocean-block-storage-volume) correctly, I can create a keyfile on the disk itself, and use it as a second passphrase for the partition. Does this mean that I only have to manually enter my own passphrase once, during initial creation of the LUKS volume, and I can then forget my own passphrase?

If this is possible, what are the security implications of having the new passphrase on the disk itself?

Comment: The security implications depend on, **what are you protecting against?** Many things are possible with LUKS, but my main question would be, what is LUKS on a VM meant to protect from (in your situation)?

Comment: @u1686_grawity: data security after you terminate your contract - you don't want whoever gets your bit of SSD potentially seeing your data. I suppose this could also happen in some cases while you still have a contract.

Comment: You can ponder the use of tang/clevis which leaves the secret on the client (vps) but in encrypted form. the clevis part queries tang server(s) in order to decrypt it. This is intended for unattended decryption, but the security implications have to be understood. This requires additional infrastructure somewhere on Internet (the tang servers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible – most Linux distributions support unlocking LUKS volumes on boot per /etc/crypttab (either using a keyfile or prompting for a passphrase), and a keyfile works the same way as a passphrase, and LUKS supports adding multiple passphrases (keyslots) to a volume, so everything done in the tutorial will work.

The question is whether it's *useful* to set up encryption in this way at all.

> data security after you terminate your contract - you don't want whoever gets your bit of SSD potentially seeing your data. I suppose this could also happen in some cases while you still have a contract

This is only a potential issue if you have a *dedicated* SSD – either if it's a physical system with the disks connected via SATA, or if it's a VM with the "raw" disk passed through. In that case encryption is a good idea; and although it is the hosting company's responsibility to sanitize the server before reusing it (or before throwing it away), there is indeed some slight risk that it won't happen and a used SSD will be connected. (When I rented a discount server on Hetzner, it had two mismatched SSDs that had been clearly used, but both were overwritten with random data.)

For VMs, though, that is practically never the case. What you get as a virtual "disk" is in most cases a *file* – probably a fresh .qcow2 image stored on a massive ZFS storage pool – and all modern filesystems already ensure that a new file will not "include" old data. (And since they're files, there is practical reason to reuse existing files; it is *simpler* to delete them when a VM is deleted, and create new ones when a VM is created.)

Either the disk image is one that grows on demand (where the image format keeps track of which areas are allocated), or it's a fixed-size sparse file (where the underlying filesystem keeps track of the same), or it's a fixed-size preallocated file (where the filesystem proactively zeros out the sectors), but generally you will not have pre-allocation without zeroing. *(I think I've seen that on ESXi VMFS, but no one runs VPS services on ESXi.)*

So although your LUKS setup does provide an additional layer of safety (under the assumption that the "other customer" will not get both of your disks simultaneously), and it does make it easier to purge the volume by throwing away the keyfile, it's still not particularly useful in this case.

> If this is possible, what are the security implications of having the new passphrase on the disk itself?

If there was already a risk that another customer would get your old data, then the security of such a setup would depend on the separation of the two volumes (the encrypted data from the cleartext OS volume) – it's secure if the "future customer" gains access to only one of the volumes, but not if they gain access to both.

Let's say both volumes were stored on the same disk (again, only in case it's a physical server with its own dedicated SSD), then anyone who gained access to the disk could just look at your /etc/crypttab, find the keyfile, and unlock the other volume the same way that it's unlocked on reboot.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed something fundamental here. You say "both volumes". Are there actually *two* volumes - one encrypted, one clear? I though everything happened on-the-fly? ie. the kernel only encrypts or decrypts single disk blocks as required? So if I'm only paying my provider for 20GB do I have to fit both the encrypted data and the clear version in the same 20GB?

Comment: And I missed the distinction in the VPS implementation - a VPS is probably generally implemented as a VM with an underlying disk file (which is how I originally create the qcow2 image which I install on the VPS). Presumably only the more 'expensive' ones have some sort of direct connection to an SSD? I haven't found any technical details for the ones I currently use (Ionos and Contabo),

Comment: @QF0: Well, although that's _not why_ I said "two volumes", but speaking of the way cryptsetup works, you do get a second virtual device in /dev that presents the "clear" data. Unlocking a LUKS volume doesn't directly change the behavior of (for example) /dev/sda1 – the physical volume continues to show encrypted data – instead LUKS creates a new virtual 'mapper' device under /dev/mapper that you need to use to access the clear data. (This has absolutely nothing to do with your space limits; virtual device is virtual and decryption happens on the fly.)

Comment: @QF0: The reason I said "two volumes" is because the DO tutorial does not apply to the situation where you only have the single `/` volume and want to encrypt that. (In that situation, you _couldn't_ place the decryption key on the disk itself, at least not the way the tutorial shows, though it's still technically possible but requires different steps). The DO tutorial shows as a prerequisite a completely separate virtual disk attached to the VM (with its own space allocation – and its own pricing), which is like if the VM has two physical disks connected (sda and sdb) instead of just one.

Comment: @QF0: As for VMs, I believe it's even less likely for the 'expensive' ones to have direct access... a directly connected SSD is a point of failure – it cannot be replaced easily if it dies, and it prevents live migration of the VM if the server is unhealthy – not to mention it probably gives you less performance (I assume) than a massive storage pool does. It's when you get a dedicated "bare metal" server that has dedicated bare-metal SSDs as well.